Can you change locale of default form validation messages?
Is there a way to change locale of default form validation messages so that no matter the browser’s language they are always displayed in English.
I don’t want to set custom messages via setCustomValidity, I want to use browser’s messages but I want them always in English.
Code sample showing intended use:
      [...e.currentTarget.elements].reduce((acc, el) => {
        if (el instanceof HTMLInputElement || el instanceof HTMLTextAreaElement)
          if (el.validationMessage)
            return { ...acc, [el.name]: el.validationMessage };

        return acc;
      }, {})


It is not 100% clear to me what you would like the invalid message to look like. Here you have two different versions. The first uses the setCustomValidity() method and the second has a custom setup where the browser message is not showing, but shows a message in HTML instead.


document.forms.form01.addEventListener('invalid', e => {
  e.target.setCustomValidity("This is the custom message");
}, true);

document.forms.form02.addEventListener('invalid', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.target.classList.add('invalid');
}, true);

document.forms.form02.addEventListener('input', e => {
  if (e.target.validity.valid) {
    e.target.classList.remove('invalid');
  }
});
input~span {
  display: none;
}

input.invalid~span {
  display: inline;
}
<p>Form01</p>
<form name="form01">
  <input type="text" name="query" required>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
<p>Form02</p>
<form name="form02">
  <input type="text" name="query" required>
  <span>This is the custom message</span>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>



